# react-native reload doesnt work

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I can't be sure it happened because of that but I updated my project name using `react-native-rename` and rebuild the project couple of hours later. Since then I cant reload my project on device.

*Note* 
On simulator it works , not working only on real device. Running `npm-start` return :

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                              │
│  Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.                                         │
│                                                                              │
│  Keep Metro running while developing on any JS projects. Feel free to        │
│  close this tab and run your own Metro instance if you prefer.               │
│                                                                              │
│  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                    │
│                                                                              │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Looking for JS files in
   /Users/Project/Client 


Metro Bundler ready.

Loading dependency graph, done.
```

and never updating no matter what. I tried to look for `.lock` inside `.git` as suggested here [#4357](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4357) but I can't find the `.git` directory so I believe it isnt the issue.

I also tried `rm -rf /usr/local/var/run/watchman && brew uninstall watchman && brew install watchman` as suggested here [#10889](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10889) without any luck.

Along the route I tried as well `watchman watch-del-all` and `rm -fr /usr/local/var/run/watchman/$USER-state`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set a debug server address for a real device.

1. Make sure your laptop and your phone are on the same Wi-Fi network.
2. Open your React Native app on your device.
3. You'll see a red screen with an error. This is OK. The following steps will fix that.
4. Open the in-app Developer menu.
5. Go to Dev Settings → Debug server host for device.
6. Type in your machine's IP address and the port of the local dev server (e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081).
7. Go back to the Developer menu and select Reload JS.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#method-2-connect-via-wi-fi

Comment: yes apparently my phone disconnected from the wifi and I didn't notice that.